# How to do page / content transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm quite new to this all so sorry for my lack of terminology.

I was looking at [this site](http://www.estudiopatagon.com/tf/wp-vcard-colores/) and I was wondering how I do the content/page change without reloading the page.

Could someone point me in the right direction? What is that JavaScript? CSS transitions? jQuery?  Or could you show me some code? Any help would be amazing; I've been looking around for a while can't find anything like it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a simple slider, just instead of slide images, it slide content (nested divs, img, lists). I checked the code for you and is using this **jQuery plugin**: [SudoSlider plugin](http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/)

Do not reinvent the wheel by writing your own plugin, you can see few demos here, but [this one](http://webbies.dk/assets/files/SudoSlider/package/demos/rich%20content.html) is very close to the example using auto height. This is how you can use it on your site:

#### Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var sudoSlider = $("#slider").sudoSlider();
    });
</script>
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="slider" >
    <ul>
        <li><div> .... </div></li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum text + image</li>
        <li>List, maps, ...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's [JQuery animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).  It's a (very slick, but still) typical carousel effect, where you have a slider div that extends beyond the visible screen, and its left margin is animated to create the effect.

It's straightforward to create the basic effect (but of course a lot of work to create something that looks as good as the link):

1. Set `overflow-x: hidden` to a container div
2. Add a slider div inside the container, and slide elements within the slider
3. Add navigation buttons, and on click animate the slider's left offset (keeping track of the current position)

[Here's a really basic example.](http://jsfiddle.net/7RU6w/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I could say that it's possible to use all of the mentioned options :)

Basically you can use something like http://bxslider.com/ to achieve what you want just instead using of img elements inside list items use some content items.